# Social media data sets for data science and exploration?

Tags: social-media

I'm looking for some open data sets of social media apps (messaging app, networking app, user sharing app, etc...) that I can use to practice modeling and visualizing within the context of social media products.

Comment: it's a pretty broad question. have you had a look through the social media tag? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Answer (score 1):

Although question is not stated quite precisely in the first place, I will try to give few potentially useful recommendations:

1. [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/) (SNAP) - Contains 15 datasets regarding to social networks specifically, but also to communication, road, internet and many other types of networks.
2. [Customer Support on Twitter](https://www.kaggle.com/thoughtvector/customer-support-on-twitter) - Kaggle's dataset containing over 3 million replies from 20 biggest brands on Twitter, closely related to questions of market psychology and analysis.
3. [May 2015 Reddit Comments](https://www.kaggle.com/reddit/reddit-comments-may-2015) - Relatively small portion of previously published ~ [1.7 billion Reddit comments dataset](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/3bxlg7/i_have_every_publicly_available_reddit_comment/), given as an example for easier usage and manipulation.